# Dropwizard and jQuery ajax post json gives either 204 or 415

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post, dropwizard

I've been trying to find a solution how to send json data to dropwizard server with jQuery, but it seems to be like mission impossible.

My Dropwizard resource looks like this:

```
package resources;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import models.Blog;

import com.yammer.metrics.annotation.Timed;

import config.SimpleApiConfiguration;

@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class IndexResource {

    private final SimpleApiConfiguration conf;

    public IndexResource(SimpleApiConfiguration conf){
        this.conf = conf;
        Blog b = new Blog("Day 12: OpenCV--Face Detection for Java Developers",
                "https://www.openshift.com/blogs/day-12-opencv-face-detection-for-java-developers");
        conf.addBlog(b);
    }


    @GET
    @Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Timed
    public List<Blog> index() {
        List<Blog> l = conf.getBlogs();
        return l;
     }

    @POST
    @Timed
    public Response addBlog(@Valid Blog blog){
        conf.addBlog(blog);
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
And my html+jQuery looks like this:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sendBlogs(){
            var blogInfo = JSON.stringify({
                title: "Nice blog",
                url: "http://nice.blog.com/1"
            });
            var url = "http://localhost:8080/";
            $.ajax({
               url:         url,
                type:        "POST",
                data:        blogInfo,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType:    "json",
                success:     function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                  alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onClick="sendBlogs()">POST it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

If I remove the contentType line from ajax POST I get 415 error message. And if it's there I get 204 (no content).

If I use curl command from terminal everything works just fine.

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "title" : "awesome blog", "url" : "http://really awesome/" }' http://localhost:8080/
```

I would still like to use my "api" from the browser instead of the command line though.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is data saved correctly in the 204 case?

Comment: Hi, according to firebug the ajax post doesn't send the data. If I remove the contentType paramater from post, then I can see the body and it's correct, but then I get 415 error.

Comment: Aha. The domain your web page originates from is also on localhost:8080? It looks like you are posting to '/' - is this correct?

Comment: The dropwizard uses port 8080 by default and I've added the IndexResource to use @Path("/").

Also the curl uses same address curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "title" : "awesome blog", "url" : "http://really awesome/" }' http://localhost:8080/

Comment: Aha - then I think your jquery thing is broken somehow. Can't spot anything obvious right away though....

Comment: (That was probably obvious to you already! :-) ) How are you calling the js function?

Comment: Since this is just a dummy test I have button with onClick="addBlogs()" :D

Comment: or sendBlogs() maybe? ;-)

Comment: Ah true. Can't read my own code. But still it's kinda odd that this behaves this way -.-"

Comment: IS this a *normal* button in a form? The default event of posting the form to the server maybe also happens? If the form is lacking data it may be the reason of "no content". It can be omitted with e.preventDefaults() in the script.

Comment: Updated the original post, there is now the whole html page.

Comment: Are you serving the HTML from your dropwizard server?

Comment: Nope. It's just a static website, which is on the same computer.

Comment: That is probably why it won't work. Browsers don't like that. Try to serve the web page from the same server and you'll be fine. (How to do it with dropwizard? No idea.... but shouldn't be too hard. ;-) I would pick sinatra for a thing like this.... )

Comment: You want to try a [dropwizard view](http://dropwizard.io/manual/views.html) for this.

Comment: Actually no, since my goal is to have standalone JSON api (without dynamic html) and standalone frontend. My only question is that why it doesn't work. Should I need to define something in dropwizard settings?

Comment: Also it's funny that the curl from terminal works.

Comment: the browser won't let you post to any server from a local file so you need to put your web page in something that looks like a server to the browser. You could just put the file statically served behind apache or nginx for example.

Comment: I added the test.html file to apache and now run in from localhost/test.html and it's still the same issue. With contenType I get 204 message and without it I get 415 error.

Comment: javascript console saying anything useful?

Comment: It is saying that the result is either 204 or 415. otherwise it would not be making the Ajax post

Comment: Seems like your ajax call is broken somehow. I would like to try it myself to understand what is going on but no time at the moment.